# Objective-C: How to populate an NSTableView from an NSArrayController, and save selected indexes with Shared Defaults Controller?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, preferences, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSTableView that I want to load it's value from an NSArrayController.  The array is built dynamically, and has the potential to change.  I also want to save the selected indexes in NSUserDefaults, ideally by binding to Shared User Defaults Controller, but I can't see how to make the happen in bindings.  Is there a way to do this?

Expanding..

In my array, I have a instances of a custom class.  I only want to display an NSString field, a name.  This is a multiple-select table view.  I'd like to have them saved as soon as they are changed.

I know how to save fields to preferences using the Shared User Defaults Controller though bindings.  I know how to set the TableView to use an array controller to display the data I wanted displayed.

I just can't seem to do both at the same time.

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic with very little information.  What kind of information is in your array, and how do you want it to appear in a text view?  What selected indexes do you want to save?  Is this a single selection? do you want to save a series of selections? when in the process do you want to save them? -- etc,etc.  Please provide more detail on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the array controller's Selection Indexes to the Shared User Defaults Controller with a Controller Key of "values" and a Model Key Path of whatever you want to call it.  You also need to choose the NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData value transformer.  Then in your code when you want to retrieve the selected indexes, you could do this (here I'm just logging it, and I used the name "selIndxs" in my binding):

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[ud valueForKey:@"selIndxs"]]);
```

Comment: When I bind the TableView to the array controller, the list of names populates perfectly when I run the application.  When a I also bind the selection indices the the TableView displays ( as each of the names.  This is the problem I've been having, but haven't been able to get around.

Comment: Can you describe how you're binding the selection indexes?  Sounds like something is set up wrong in your bindings.

Comment: Sure.  I select the Table View.  Drop down Table Content.  Drop down Selection Indices. Check Bind To: Shared User Defaults Controller.  Enter 'names' in the Model Key Path.  Set Value Transformer to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData.  That's it.  Then I build it, and the names are messed up in the TableView.  When I uncheck Bind to: the TableView displays the names correctly again.

Comment: I think it's the array controller's Selection Indexes that you should bind to the user defaults controller, not the table's.